# Messaging with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to figure out how  can I type a command in `#channel1` and have the `discord bot` send a message(and plan in the future on having it clear as well) in `#channel2`

This is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
Bot = new Discord.Client();
gbot = new Discord.Guild();
const token = '....';
bot.on('message', msg =>{
    if(msg.content === 'Hello'){
        var channel2 = 
        gbot.channels.find(val => 
        val.name === "channel2")             
        msg.channel2.send("hey");
    }
}
bot.login(token);
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
>       at Client.

Comment: I'm afraid rafael duarte's answer didnt help. Bump

Comment: You're trying to find a channel on a newly initiated class...?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an error at `msg.channel2.send("hey")`, it should be `channel2.send("hey")`, also, as Kareem mentioned, you shouldn't be initializing a new Guild object, you should use the one that is part of the message.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = '....';
bot.on('message', msg =>{
    if(msg.content === 'Hello'){           
        var channel2 =  
        msg.guild.channels.find(val => 
        val.name === "channel2");          
        channel2.send("hey");
    }
}
bot.login(token);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, you shouldn't initialize a new Guild object, you need to use the one that is associated with the message

Answer (score 1):

Like Rafeal said you want to use `channel2.send()` ,
additionally the way you're getting the channel is a bit weird. It seems you're creating a new guild instead of getting the one where the message was sent from. you can find this in the message object.

Try this code instead.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = '....';
bot.on('message', msg =>{
    if(msg.content === 'Hello'){
        var channel2 = 
        msg.guild.channels.find(val => 
        val.name === "channel2")             
        channel2.send("hey");
    }
}
bot.login(token);
```